# Diagonalization with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

In my Linear Algebra course I came across the following statement:

If $A$ is a $2*2$ *real* matrix with two complex eigenvalues $\lambda_1 =a+bi$ and $\lambda_2 =a-bi$ then $A=PCP^{-1}$ with $\ P = \begin{bmatrix} Re(\vec{v}) & Im(\vec{v}) \end{bmatrix}$ and $C = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$

I do not understand what this represents. Is it a diagonalization? This doesn't make sense because $C$ is not a diagonal matrix. Is it a similarity transformation? This maybe makes sense because the eigenvalues of $C$ are indeed $\lambda_1 =a+bi$ and $\lambda_2 =a-bi$.  However, if this is the case why is it that $\ P = \begin{bmatrix} Re(\vec{v}) & Im(\vec{v}) \end{bmatrix}$.  Will there only ever by one eigenvector produced?

Comment: Yes, it's a similarity transformation; $P$ is changing the basis to yield $C$, which is called a conformal (or a rotation-scaling) matrix. And no, there are two eigenvectors, but they're conjugates, since if $Av=\lambda v$, then $\overline{Av}=\overline{A}\overline{v}=A\overline{v}=\overline{\lambda v}=\overline{\lambda}\overline{v}$, so the conjugate of $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$.

Comment: Ok. So to compose $P$ can one use either of the two eigenvectors produced?

Comment: Im not sure I see where you are going with the hint @rubertos

Comment: You can also look up Real Canonical Form.